# How to filter elements from a tuple using a list as a filter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Had a filter that parsed through a list but then realised I needed to zip the original list to number each line before i filtered and now I'm not sure how to use the same filter on each of the _._2 tuple elements

```
val list = List("def", "var", "val")
val source = Source.fromFile("..\scala.file").getLines.toList
```

```
val filtered = source filter(line => list.exists(word => list.contains(word)))) 
//before
```

```
val filtered = (1 to source.length) zip source 
                   filter(line => list.exists(word => list.contains(word)))) 
//after
```

Cannot get function working with tuple.

Supposed to filter out each tuple that doesn't contain any instances of the elements from the list

Comment: First, do not use `(1 to source.length) zip source`. It is unnecessary expensive, use `val zipped = source.zipWithIndex` instead. Second you need to access the second element of the tuple, `val filtered = zipped.filter(tuple => list.exists(word => tuple._2.contains(word))`. However, I personally do not like the `._2` method on tuples, it is not too clear when reading code, so I would use: `val filtered = zipped.filter { case (idx, line) => list.exists(word => line.contains(word) }`, using **pattern matching** to unpack tuples leads to more readable code _IMHO_.

Comment: Scratch that, managed to get the pattern matching method working by swapping the idx and line, thank you :)

Comment: oh yeah, I am on my cellphone right now so I could not test the code, sorry for those little bugs. Yes, you are right, `zipWithIndex` puts the index on the right _(just checked the **Scaladoc**)_, so you need to use `._1` or invert the order of the match for it to work. The `Any` part is weird, aren't you trying to do something else in the filter?

Comment: BTW, if I am not mistaken `zipWithIndex` starts with _zero_ (**0**), instead of with _one_ (**1**). Also, you seem to need the index in the left, so you may want to `map` (before or after the `filter`) - `map { case (line, idx) => (idx + 1) -> line }`. Also, if you are doing many transformations to a collection, is better to use `iterator` to make them lazy & call `toList` at the very end, which will speed up the code.

Comment: the index doesn't need to be on the left side of the tuple i just need to be able identify the line by the index, any tips for processing the tuple to drop all the characters/words that aren't in the list?

Comment: If I get you well, you need to extract for each line the words which match any word of the list? - If so, you can wither write a proper regex to extract such words _(take a look to jwvh's answer for insights about that)_, or other simple _(maybe not as performant solution)_ would be something like `lines.zipWithIndex.map { case (line, idx) => idx -> line.trim.toLowerCase.split("//W+").iterator.filter(word => words.contains(word)).toList }`, where words is the list with all words you care, note I would make such list a set instead to make the contains call **O(1)**.

Comment: Anyways, if you got more questions it would be better to open a new question on the site. Also, you may first try to solve those by yourself before opening the question. Generally speaking, a _"requisite"_ for opening questions is to provide at least one failed attempt to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
val list = List("def", "var", "val")
val matcher = list.mkString(".*(", "|", ").*")

io.Source
  .fromFile("..\scala.file")
  .getLines
  .zipWithIndex
  .filter(_._1 matches matcher)
  .map{case (txt,idx) => (idx+1,txt)}  //optional
  .toList
```

Comment: Two questions. First, if using a regex, would not it be better to compile it, instead of passing it to the `matches` method which will recompile it everytime, you can use`r.unapplySeq(str).isDefined` for that _(I agree it is not pleasant to look at, that is why I always create a `matches` method on an **implicit value class**)_. - Second, will regex stop once first match? I am assuming the list is long and each line short, thus stopping iterations on the first one seems better than avoid scanning the second one. _(obviously performance assumptions without tests are meaningless)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez; 1st - I agree, compiling once and pattern matching thereafter should be more performant. I was going for concise expression over maximized throughput. 2nd - I assume (but don't know for sure) that regex will terminate as-early-as-possible. The regex engines have been around long enough to expel most pointless inefficiencies.